# Power Series to solve non linear differential equations.

Tags: analysis, power-series

I've been revising Power series recently and their application when it comes to solving linear differential equations, but in this question I'm not sure what to do when it's a non linear function.
I tried doing the same steps I do normally but these end up a mess.
Any help would be appreciated.

> Consider the differential equation $y'-y^{2}=0$ with initial condition $y(0)=c$. Notice that this is a non-linear equation. Suppose that $f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$ is a power-series
>   solution.
>   $(i)$ Find $ a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, a_{4}, a_{5}$
>   $(ii)$ Guess the correct formula for $a_{n}$
>   $(iii)$ Assuming your guess in (b) is correct, find the radius of convergence of your powersolution.

Comment: It's messy, but you just square the infinite sum! What is more often done is you write down the first N terms, square via the multinomial theorem, and just make sure you kept enough powers of $x$ to have the correct series:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still equate coefficients, as always.  The $y'$ term looks like

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n$$

The $y^2$ term is guided by the following:

$$y^2(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n$$

where

$$c_n = \sum_{m=0}^n a_m \, a_{n-m}$$

So, equating coefficients of $x^0$, we get $a_1-a_0^2=0$.
Equating coeffs of $x^1$, we get

$$2 a_2=2 a_0 a_1$$

and so on.

Comment: Hmmm, aren't the terms $y^2(x)$ equal to $c_n x^{2n} $  instead of $c_n x^{n} $
And y' should include $x^(n-1)$ instead of $x^n$?

Oh, wait a second, Ron skipped steps, he's already reindexed.